# Angular2 - Forms Custom Validation - Make an reference outside validation function()

Tags: angular

I'm creating my own validation for an specific FormControl but I can't figure out how to make an reference to an external value defined outside my validation function.

**CODE:**

```
  @Component({
      selector: 'city-autocomplete',
      template: `
     <label for="incidade">Cidade/Comarca:</label>
     <input type="text" class="autocomplete-imput" id="incidade"
      [formControl]=inputcidade
      >
     `,
      styleUrls: ['./city-autocomplete.component.scss']
    })

    export class CityAutocompleteComponent {

    extenalValue :boolean = false



     inputcity = new FormControl('', [this.cityValidator]);

    //My Validator:
      cityValidator(ctrl: AbstractControl) {

        const isValid = this.extenalValue // <== this is UNDEFINED

        return isValid ? null : {
          cityValidator: {
            valid: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

HTML:

**ERROR:**

It's shows extenalValue is undefined.

As I could see, Abstract Control runs BEFORE @Component so I can't define anything outside the validator function.

**MY QUESTION:**

How should I make reference to values outside this function ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference binding to the component class is gone when using a function reference.

There a various ways to fix this, one option is:

```
inputcity = new FormControl('', [this.cityValidator.bind(this)]);
```

A little side note. What's a validator function doing within a component?

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do it.
I made this validation function inside component because it will be only 2 or 3 lines of code and it will be used only here. 
I thought that doesn't worth to create  another file in my app with a new directive/export function and insert this inside barrels (index.ts) and module just because that.